# Oracle SQL: Case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not sure where to put the case statement whether in select or where clause. I am trying to get data from table c when cnt_subj = MEPC_PL then metric_id will be equal to 6135 from table m. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance! :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    m.metric_id         AS metric_id,
    m.subject_abbrevn   AS p_subj,
    m.table_abbrevn     AS cnt_subj,
    c.p_id              AS p_id,
    c.cnt_id            AS cnt_id,
    c.gl_id             AS gl_id,
    case c.cnt_subj
    when 'MEPC_PL' then 6135
    end m.metric_id
FROM
    T_CROMS_CAT_T   m,
    croms_qc_currency_1_v c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the query you are looking for:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    m.metric_id         AS metric_id,
    m.subject_abbrevn   AS p_subj,
    m.table_abbrevn     AS cnt_subj,
    c.p_id              AS p_id,
    c.cnt_id            AS cnt_id,
    c.gl_id             AS gl_id,
FROM croms_qc_currency_1_v c
INNER JOIN T_CROMS_CAT_T m ON DECODE(c.cnt_subj, 'MEPC_PL', 6135, NULL) = m.metric_id;
```

Do you actually need the `DISTINCT`? Is there more than one row with those IDs?
Also, you can expand this if you have other `CNT_SUBJ` values which you need to translate.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much! Just 1 question, the null in the decode I can just skip it if I have more than 1 condition right? For example, I want it 'MEPC_PL' then return 6135 and 'MEKM_PL' then return 6136.

Comment: @VincentToong yes you can omit the NULL and it will work the same. Oracle will still return NULL if there isn’t a match. I would also be remiss if I didn’t mention that if you have a bunch of these, it would probably be better to create a crosswalk table and join it in rather than needing to constantly update your code if there are any changes to the mappings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add an `ELSE` condition to your `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    m.metric_id         AS metric_id,
    m.subject_abbrevn   AS p_subj,
    m.table_abbrevn     AS cnt_subj,
    c.p_id              AS p_id,
    c.cnt_id            AS cnt_id,
    c.gl_id             AS gl_id,
    CASE c.cnt_subj WHEN 'MEPC_PL' THEN 6135 ELSE m.metric_id END AS metric_id_new
FROM T_CROMS_CAT_T m
INNER JOIN croms_qc_currency_1_v c
    ON <some join condition here>
```

Comment: I think its very close to what I am trying to achieve, but instead of adding it in as a new column, I want the m.metric_id = 6135 instead. The logic is, from table c, check the column whether the data inside equal to MEPC_PL, if yes extract the row, set metric_id to 6135 and get the data from table m with row with metric id 6135. In this case, maybe I should put the case expression in where clause?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question to avoid further speculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can phrase the `JOIN` condition as:

```
FROM T_CROMS_CAT_T m JOIN
     croms_qc_currency_1_v c
     ON m.metric_id = 6135 AND c.cnt_subj = 'MEPC_PL'
```

Very importantly:  This does not impede the optimizer, so it should be much faster than `DECODE()` or `CASE` expressions in the `ON` clause.